# Throttle or kill large file uploads in asp.net (httphandler, webapi, or mvc controller)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

I need low level control over http file uploads so I can kill an upload early.

Background:
We have a application (an httphandler) that serves downloads of media.  It is able to throttle the downloads and also it's able to embed some encrypted meta-data in the file as it is being served to the client.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I'm trying to figure out how to do the reverse of what I wrote above.  I want to give our users the ability to upload one of these files so that our app can extract the encrypted data, decrypt it, and present it to the user.  The problem is that these files can be big (200+ MB).  The metadata though, is at the beginning of the file and we're able to read it even if the file is just a fragment.

So, does anyone know how I can gain low level control over the file upload so I can get the first N bytes of the file and then kill the upload?  I'm hoping this is similar to the code I wrote for throttling downloads.  I'm open to doing this via an httphandler, the webapi, or any other way that would be easy.